# Need Minimum number of sign tab in docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending an envelope with sign in anywhere option provided by docusign API.

I would like to request minimum 3 signs with sign in anywhere option.

Is that possible with Docusign API ?

I already google this but I am not able to find exact solution what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're allowing the signer to sign anywhere (i.e., using "free form signing" instead of placing DocuSign Signature tabs within the Envelope), then it's not possible to require a specific number of signatures.  To require a specific number of signatures, you'd need to place (required) Signature tabs at specific locations within the Envelope, and the signer would not be able to complete/submit the Envelope until they signed in all "required" locations.